# Animating UICollectionViewCell label on selection

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I have a custom `UICollectionViewCell` with a custom label in it. When the user taps the cell, I'd like the animate the appearance of the custom label. I've tried keeping a reference variable and calling `collectionView.reloadData()`, but in my `cellForItemAtIndexPath` the update doesn't animate. Rather, it happens instantly. How can I animate the label's font and size changes?

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        self.flatPicker.reloadData()
        self.variable = indexPath.row

}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UICollectionViewCell

        cell.label.text = self.array[indexPath.row]

        if indexPath.row == variable {

            UIView.animateWithDuration(2, animations: { 

                cell.label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(12)
                cell.label.textColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()

            })


        } else {

            UIView.animateWithDuration(2, animations: {

                cell.label.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(11)
                cell.label.textColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()

            })

        }

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Don't reload... get the reference in didSelectItemAtIndexPath, and animate just that cell.

I am not sure, but I think there is a method, cellForRowAtIndexPath, and after that you can get the reference in the didSelectItemAtIndexPath, and animate there.

Answer (score 0):

Fonts and text colors are not animatable.

What you can do is layer two labels on top of each other with either the bold/regular attributes and cross fade between the two using `.alpha`

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't acccess the selected cell in cellForItemAtIndexPath but rather in didSelectItemAtIndexPath.

Retreive the current selected cell and animate it like so

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
   let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)
   cell.label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(12)
   cell.label.textColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
```

}

As David said fonts and colors aren't animatable properties.